# t-sql join query for a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query for a view but I don't have a hold of it.
I have two tables

```
         user_roles
    id  user_id   role_id                
    1     1        4
    2     1        1
    3     1        2
    4     1        3

        user_roles_hst
    id  UserRolesID  RoleEnabled     creator
     1     1              1            1    
     2     1              0            1    
     3     1              1            1    
     4     2              0            1    
     5     2              1            1    
     6     3              0            1
     7     4              0            1
```

Now i want a view with all the user roles and their latest enabled status
like so

```
       vw_user_roles
    user_id    role_id    RoleEnabled
      1          4             1
      1          1             1
      1          2             0
      1          3             0
```

The user_roles_hst stores history of role status changes as they are enabled or disabled but in the vw_user_roles, i need the latest status for each or the role_id

Query:

```
select * from 
(select x.user_id, x.UserRolesID, x.RoleEnabled from 
(select h.id, u.user_id, h.UserRolesID, h.RoleEnabled from UserRoles u, UserRoles_HST h 
where u.id = h.UserRolesID
group by h.id, h.UserRolesID, h.RoleEnabled, u.user_id
) x
order by x.id desc
) y
group by y.user_id, y.UserRolesID, y.RoleEnabled
```

I tried the above query but then i realize i can't use order by in a subquery

I need help on how to get the right query.

Comment: For for roleid 4 it is RoleEnabled as 1? It should be 0 rite?

Comment: You can use `order by` in a subquery if you also use `top 1`

Comment: for each role that is enabled or disabled, a new record is created and that record has 1 for enabled or 2 for disabled depending on what was done.

Comment: What is the column for the role?  What is the column in the history table for the user?  And how does role 4 have enabled set to 1?  The only "4" in the sample history has enabled as 0.

Comment: How does `user_roles_hst` store the history without a date?  Are you just assuming that the largest value of `user_roles_hst.id` must have been added last?

Comment: @BaconBits, thre is a date, i'm just not displaying it since `id` can also serve the purpose

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the history table doesnt have a column for user, you have to link it to the user_roles table using the UserRolesID

Comment: @GordonLinoff From the existing query: `UserRoles.id = user_roles_hst.UserRolesID`.

Comment: @AhmadTijani I would definitely use the date value and not the id value.  The assumption that the most recent record will have the greatest ID is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    declare @user_roles table ( id  int, user_id int, role_id  int);
    insert into @user_roles values            
        (1,     1,        4),
        (2,     1,        1),
        (3,     1,        2),
        (4,     1,        3)

    declare @user_roles_hst table (id  int, UserRolesID int, RoleEnabled  int,  creator int);
    insert into @user_roles_hst values
         (1,     1,              1,            1),    
         (2,     1,              0,            1),   
         (3,     1,              1,            1),    
         (4,     2,              0,            1),    
         (5,     2,              1,            1),    
         (6,     3,              0,            1),
         (7,     4,              0,            1)

    select r.user_id,    
           r.role_id, 
           a.RoleEnabled
    from @user_roles r outer apply (select top 1 *
                                    from @user_roles_hst h
                                    where h.UserRolesID = r.id
                                    order by id desc) a;
```

Comment: i like this one too,

`outer_apply` handles record in `user_roles` but not in `user_roles_hst`

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @user_roles table (id int, user_id int, role_id int)
Declare @user_roles_hst table (id int, userrolesid int, roleenabled int, creator int)

insert into @user_roles values
(1,1,4),
(2,1,1),
(3,1,2),
(4,1,3)

insert into @user_roles_hst values
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 0, 1),
(3, 1, 1, 1),
(4, 2, 0, 1),
(5, 2, 1, 1),
(6, 3, 0, 1),
(7, 4, 0, 1)

select ur.user_id,ur.role_id,x.roleenabled
from @user_roles ur
join (
Select row_number() over (partition by userrolesid order by id desc) rn,*
from @user_roles_hst) x on ur.id = x.userrolesid
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The max id from `vw_user_roles` for each user_id:

```
SELECT max(id) as maxID FROM user_roles_hst GROUP BY userRolesID;
```

Using that to get the records from your tables for each `maxID`:

```
SELECT t2.user_id, t1.UserRolesID, t1.rolesEnabled
FROM user_roles_hst t1
    INNER JOIN user_roles t2 ON
        t1.userRolesID = t2.role_id
WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) as maxID FROM user_roles_hst GROUP BY userRolesID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming:

- `creator` is really the user.
- `userRoleId` is the user role
- By latest, you mean "biggest id"

Then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select urh.creator as user_id, userRoleId, as role_id, role_enabled as enabled
from (select urh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by creator, userRoleId order by id desc) as seqnum
      from user_roles_hst urh
     ) urh
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this only gave me one record and I'm expecting exactly 4, i.e. all the records in `user_roles`